# Express JS: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type number

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, koa, shopify-app

I am going through this TUT to make a private app in shopify [build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react](https://developers.shopify.com/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/embed-your-app-in-shopify)

The TUT uses [koa](https://expressjs.com/) but I am using [express](https://koajs.com/). Partly because I know express and wanted to see if I could abstract what was going on and apply it in a different context.

When I get to [Authenticate and test your app](http://TypeError%20[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:%20The%20%22url%22%20argument%20must%20be%20of%20type%20string.%20Received%20type%20number%20%20%20%20%20at%20Url.parse%20(url.js:154:11)%20%20%20%20%20at%20urlParse%20(url.js:148:13)%20%20%20%20%20at%20Object.urlResolve%20[as%20resolve]%20(url.js:659:10)%20%20%20%20%20at%20/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express-shopify-auth/index.js:190:19%20%20%20%20%20at%20Function.shop%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/server/server.js:28:14)%20%20%20%20%20at%20middleware%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express-shopify-auth/index.js:168:25)%20%20%20%20%20at%20Layer.handle%20[as%20handle_request]%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)%20%20%20%20%20at%20trim_prefix%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)%20%20%20%20%20at%20/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7%20%20%20%20%20at%20Function.process_params%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)%20%20%20%20%20at%20next%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)%20%20%20%20%20at%20session%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express-session/index.js:468:7)%20%20%20%20%20at%20Layer.handle%20[as%20handle_request]%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)%20%20%20%20%20at%20trim_prefix%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)%20%20%20%20%20at%20/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7%20%20%20%20%20at%20Function.process_params%20(/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)) they want one to do this:

> Add the HTTPS version of your ngrok forwarding URL and your store’s
>   URL to the following placeholder and load it in a browser:
>
> Tip

Which results in my error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type number
    at Url.parse (url.js:154:11)
    at urlParse (url.js:148:13)
    at Object.urlResolve [as resolve] (url.js:659:10)
    at /Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express-shopify-auth/index.js:190:19
    at Function.shop (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/server/server.js:28:14)
    at middleware (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express-shopify-auth/index.js:168:25)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at session (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express-session/index.js:468:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Sites/scheduled-promo-bar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

This is my server.js:

```
/* eslint-disable vars-on-top */
require('isomorphic-fetch');
var express = require('express');
var next = require('next');
var ShopifyAuth = require('express-shopify-auth');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var session = require('express-session');

dotenv.config();

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
var app = next({ dev });

var { SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY, SHOPIFY_API_KEY } = process.env;

app.prepare().then(() => {
  var auth = ShopifyAuth.create({
    appKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
    appSecret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
    baseUrl: port,
    authPath: '/auth',
    authCallbackPath: '/auth/callback',
    authSuccessUrl: '/success',
    authFailUrl: '/fail',
    scope: ['read_products'],
    shop(req, done) {
      return done(null, req.query.shop);
    },
    onAuth(req, res, shop, accessToken, done) {
      // save auth info to session
      req.session.shopify = { shop, accessToken };
      return done();
    },
  });

  var server = express();

  server.use(
    session({
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
    })
  );

  server.use(auth);

  server.get('/success', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.session.shopify);
  });

  server.get('/fail', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Authentication failed');
  });

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing port in baseurl property which is a number. You should add url over there.